# Loop for grabbing certain char's in a string

Tags: java

If I have a string and an int, I want to be able to create a loop that will print the first char of the string, followed by each the char at value of that int.

e.g. If I have the word "Miracle" and the int 2, the result should be "Mrce". My code does this, but stops a char short for certain words.

```
  System.out.println(str.charAt(0));


  while (n <= str.length())
  {
    System.out.println(str.charAt(n));
    n = n+n;
  }
```

This works for strings like "abcdefg" and int 3. It prints "adg", but if the string is "miracle" and int 2, it prints "mrc" and not "mrce".

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the "n= n+n" statement.

Because if the int is 3 and the string is greater than 3 it will loop, but in the n=n+n statement it will loop enough that n will be greater than str length and it halts.

How can I correct this?

Comment: Take `n == 2`. Now, after one execution, you'll have `n == 4`, so after the next execution you'll have `n == 8` and not `n == 6`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, your problem is with `n=n+n` because it multiple n with 2 in every step so you must change that.

change your code like this :

```
int m = 0;
while (m < str.length())
{
   System.out.println(str.charAt(m));
   m = m+n;
}
```

Comment: <= will crash, use m < str.length()

Comment: This throws an error "String index out of range: 9", I think I have tried that before and threw it out because of this error. EDIT: Nope, this worked with the <= replaced. Thanks

Comment: use `print` instead of `println`

Comment: @wayoo I fixed that no check my solution

Comment: @NeerajJain I just copy what OP used

Answer (score 3):

`n = n+n;` means that in each iteration you are multiplying your `n` by `2`, so

```
iteration | n 
----------+-------
1         | 3
2         | 3+3=6
3         | 6+6=12
```

and so on.

What you need is temporary variable (iterator) which will use `n` but will not change it.

Generally more readable way to write it would be with `for` loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i = i+n){//or `i += n`
     ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^
//   start at   continue when     in next step
    System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer with a counterquestion: where is this mentionned int? What walue should it have, and what value does it have?

In short, you should have one variable which has the step value and another variable which acts as a cursor.

Something like

```
int cursor = 0;

while (cursor <= str.length()) {
    System.out.println(str.charAt(cursor));
    cursor += stepValue;
}
```

Here you see that it is necessary to have two distinct variables here.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for first few instances as 2+ 2 = 4, but after that - its doing 4 + 4 = 8, while you need is 4 + 2 = 6.

Take a new var (v), assign it the initial value, & instead of doing `n = n + n`, do

```
n = n + v
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

```
int n = 0;
int skip = 2;
while (n < str.length())
{
  System.out.println(str.charAt(n));
  n+=skip;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have an error here:

```
n <= str.length()
```

It should be

```
n < str.length()
```

because strings are indexed from 0 to length-1.
Also make sure you are indexing from 0, not from 1.
Another thing is that you are adding a bigger number each time. So yes - you are right about n+n - it's wrong.
You should do something like this:

```
n = ...;
for (int i = 0; n * i < str.length(); ++i)
{
    int index = n * i;
    System.out.println(str.charAt());
}
```

This way you have n * 0, n * 1, n * 2, ..., which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong in your code:

- If `n == str.length()`, it will throw an exception, as it tries to
  access `str.charAt(n)`, which in that case doesn't exist.
- Another thing, `n = n + n` will change the value of `n` every time, so you 
  will add a bigger number every time instead of the same.

You could use a for-loop for a cleaner approach though:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += n) {
    System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
}
```